# Embed video on a webpage that will work on a blackberry device and windows mobile 6.5

Tags: blackberry, video, mobile, embed

I'm trying to embed a video on a website that will play on blackberry and windows mobile 6.5 devices (currently testing on a blackberry curve and acer betouch) but don't seem to be getting anywhere.

**Blackberry**
Flash doesn't work, and HTML5 video doesn't either. I can play video in the browser on youtube so can see that it is possible - using third party services like youtube isn't really an option either.

**Windows mobile 6.5** 
Same deal really, though I think Flash is the way to go (http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ says the device has flash version 9.1.something installed) but still just getting a little triangle with a 9 in when I test it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for an answer to this too. Have you found an answer yet?