# Embed a video to a webpage that will work on Blackberry/Windows Phones

Tags: javascript, blackberry, windows-mobile, mobile-website

I have been looking for an answer to this for a while with no luck. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656597/embed-video-on-a-webpage-that-will-work-on-a-blackberry-device-and-windows-mobile) gives a lot of detail to the problem I am having, but is unanswered:

> I'm trying to embed a video on a website that will play on blackberry
>   and windows mobile 6.5 devices (currently testing on a blackberry
>   curve and acer betouch) but don't seem to be getting anywhere.
>
> Blackberry Flash doesn't work, and HTML5 video doesn't either. I can
>   play video in the browser on youtube so can see that it is possible -
>   using third party services like youtube isn't really an option either.
>
> Windows mobile 6.5 Same deal really, though I think Flash is the way
>   to go (http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ says the device has
>   flash version 9.1.something installed) but still just getting a little
>   triangle with a 9 in when I test it.

My question is: **How would I embed a video to a webpage for blackberry and windows mobile?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using the `<object>` tag would be safest, as Blackberry and Windows Mobile devices should both support it. Here's a link to the Blackberry developer blog, where they explain embedding video/audio objects so they are viewable on a Blackberry device. This method should work for Windows Mobile devices as well:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6176/HTML_ref_object_564145_11.jsp

Comment: This may work for me, usually making a regular HTML page works on the older blackberries that I need to target. I will have to do some testing on it to make sure though. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

For a full overview of HTML 5 video and flash fallback (to support all devices) consider reading here..

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/video.html

Vorbis OGG may be the safest bet..

Comment: jUST a tip, it seems TinyTube.net can stream to blackberries, so you might try and see what they use under the covers.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have never looked into using OGG files, so I need to play around with it for a bit